# Error uploading google action via gactions

Tags: actions-on-google

I created a project marvin-xyz, and a json action file marvin.json
When I try to upload it with the CIA tools from google: gactions, 
I get the following error:

```
$gactions test --action_package marvin.json --project marvin-xyz
Pushing the app for the Assistant for testing...
ERROR: Failed to test the app for the Assistant
ERROR: Internal error encountered.
2017/09/28 10:35:28 Server did not return HTTP 200
```

xyz is just a placeholder here - the project exists - in both cases, the real one has been used

Any advice?

EDIT: here it the update with the verbose option

```
$gactions --verbose test --action_package marvin.json --project marvin-xyz
Checking for updates...
Successfully fetched update metadata
Finished checking for updates -- no updates available
Pushing the app for the Assistant for testing...
POST /v2/users/me/previews/marvin-xyz:updateFromAgentDraft?updateMask=previewActionPackage.actionPackage.actions%2CpreviewActionPackage.actionPackage.conversations%2CpreviewActionPackage.actionPackage.types%2CpreviewActionPackage.startTimestamp%2CpreviewActionPackage.endTimestamp HTTP/1.1
Host: actions.googleapis.com
User-Agent: Gactions-CLI/2.0.7 (darwin; amd64; stable/XYZ)
Content-Length: 697
Content-Type: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip

{"name":"users/me/previews/marvin-xyz","previewActionPackage":{"actionPackage":{"actions":[{"description":"Default Welcome Intent","fulfillment":{"conversationName":"marvin"},"intent":{"name":"actions.intent.MAIN","trigger":{"queryPatterns":[{"queryPatterns":"I want to talk to marvin"},{"queryPatterns":"talk to marvin"},{"queryPatterns":"wake up marvin"},{"queryPatterns":"is marvin there?"},{"queryPatterns":"where is marvin?"},{"queryPatterns":"hello marvin"},{"queryPatterns":"pass me to marvin"},{"queryPatterns":"marvin please"}]}},"name":"MAIN"}],"conversations":{"marvin":{"name":"marvin","url":"https://example.com/sidekick/api/v1/"}}},"name":"users/me/previews/marvin-xyz"}}
Reading credentials from: creds.data
ERROR: Failed to test the app for the Assistant
ERROR: Internal error encountered.
2017/09/29 23:37:09 Server did not return HTTP 200
```

Comment: PS. same when I use the upload instead test command

Comment: Can you update your question with the output from `gactions --verbose test --action_package marvin.json --project marvin-xyz`

Comment: Hi @Prisoner the question has been updated with --verbose

Comment: Could you paste your Action Package here? One issue might be the format of your queryPatterns. They should be an array of strings, not objects, as shown here https://devrel.git.corp.google.com/samples/assistant/actions-sdk-eliza/+/master/eliza.json